# So smooth scrolling like on this website

Tags: smooth-scrolling, smoothing

How to implement smooth scrolling like on this website?
https://boredomdoctors.com/banjo-dog/

Comment: There are number of custom scroll libraries out there, just do a quick search. Two I've used are [malihu scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and [perfect scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

I've found on [website](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Smooth_Scrolling_like_Parallax-Gor) similar solution:

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 2;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 900; // delay time
    var distance = 140; // delta point 
    // Dom where it will apply 
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time, 'easeOutExpo' );
}
```